# Where clause not working after using Date Function in SQL

Tags: sql

The `lasttime` field is a timestamp which I converted to date format `mm/dd/yyyy` using the date function, but when I run this query the filter in the where clause is not working.

```
select rule, weight, date(lasttime) as last_date_fired
from prod_frm.rules_recent
where lasttime <= '10/28/2022'
limit 2000;
```

Comment: For future reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: Anyway, what does "not working" mean? What happens? What did you expect to happen? We can't see your data to know what the code will return. Also, `The lasttime field is a timestamp which I converted to date format`...so, is it a timestamp, or isn't it? It's not clear? You didn't tag your DBMS, but it may or may not be able to do date comparisons using ambiguous date formats such as mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy. Far better to stick to something clearly defined and universal such as yyyy-mm-dd. Or just use a timestamp, like you had originally!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 1):

I am speculating that you are using MySQL here, in which case the main problem you are having is that the date literal is in an incorrect format.  Use this version:

```sql
SELECT rule, weight, DATE(lasttime) AS last_date_fired
FROM prod_frm.rules_recent
WHERE lasttime <= '2022-10-28'
-- ORDER BY <one or more columns>
LIMIT 2000;
```

Note also that using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless.  In general, you should specify some ordering with which to take the 2000 records.